# When volatile keyword is really necessary?

Tags: java, concurrency

This code taken from book *Java threads and the concurrency utilities* by Jeff Friesen :

```
public class PC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shared s = new Shared();
        new Producer(s).start();
        new Consumer(s).start();
    }
}
```

```
class Shared {
    private char c;
    private volatile boolean writeable = true;

    synchronized void setSharedChar(char c) {
        while (!writeable)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie)  {
            }
        this.c = c;
        writeable = false;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized char getSharedChar() {
        while (writeable)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie)  {
            }
        writeable = true;
        notify();
        return c;
    }
}
```

```
class Producer extends Thread {
    private final Shared s;

    Producer(Shared s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++) {
            synchronized(s) {
                s.setSharedChar(ch);
                System.out.println(ch + " produced by producer.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Consumer extends Thread {
    private final Shared s;

    Consumer(Shared s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        char ch;
        do {
            synchronized(s) {
                ch = s.getSharedChar();
                System.out.println(ch + " consumed by consumer.");
            }
        } while (ch != 'Z');
    }
}
```

I do not understand why it is necessary to make `volatile` the `writeable` field since it is only accessed by `synchronized` methods, which has the same effect as volatile (visibility + mutual exclusion for writes). And why field `writeable` needs to be `volatile` and not field `c` in this case.

And same question for next code with `balance` field : why does it need to be volatile since it is accessed already by `synchronized` `withdraw` method.

```
public class CheckingAccount {
    private volatile int balance;

    public CheckingAccount(int initialBalance) {
        balance = initialBalance;
    }

    public synchronized boolean withdraw(int amount) {
        if (amount <= balance) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 200));
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            balance -= amount;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final CheckingAccount ca = new CheckingAccount(100);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    System.out.println (name + " withdraws $10: " +
                ca.withdraw(10));
            }
        };
        Thread thdHusband = new Thread(r);
        thdHusband.setName("Husband");
        Thread thdWife = new Thread(r);
        thdWife.setName("Wife");
        thdHusband.start();
        thdWife.start();
    }
}
```

Could someone explain ?

Comment: I didn't double check, but I think you are correct.  As long as all accesses (both reads and writes) are inside a `synchronized` block, you don't need volatile.  I'd ditch that book and get *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You understood the ideas correctly. `volatile` is completely useless here and should not be used. if the book did not introduce these snippets as examples of what *not* to do, and you also pasted the entire snippet (i.e. there isn't a method you elided that accesses these fields that *is not* `synchronized` on `this`) - then that's a pretty painful error in the book. If it's an error due to the author not understanding the JMM themselves, that means the book should be tossed in the bin. If it's merely an error in the example, perhaps because it originally started out as an example using `volatile` and later on was swapped to use `synchronized`, but the author forgot to remove `volatile`, that's still a pretty egregious editing error.

Comment: thanks for the response. then the error is not only present in the book but also in the source code https://github.com/Apress/java-threads-concurrency-utilities